# Cordova - modify or remove MainActivity

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am developing a Cordova application which should run in a "Kiosk" mode - the device will be locked to that app and should not be able to exit.

To achieve this I am using a slightly modified version of [cordova-plugin-kiosk](https://github.com/honza889/cordova-plugin-kiosk), which provides an extra activity (`KioskActivity`) that is defined as a launcher (it has `android.intent.category.HOME`).

This works reasonably well. However, the app still has the original cordova MainActivity, which causes some confusion, especially as this is what gets launched by the icon in the original launcher, and by the `cordova run android` command. It also results in two entries in the Chrome remote inspector.

The `AndroidManifest.xml` looks like this at the moment:

```
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="jk.cordova.plugin.kiosk.KioskActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I would like to merge these into a single activity and do away with the confusion.

I can see 2 possible ways to do this:

1. Find a way to remove the `MainActivity` section from the `AndroidManifest.xml`, and hopefully also to make `cordova run android` run `KioskActivity` instead.
2. Find a way to modify `MainActivity` and move the code from `KioskActivity` into it.

However, I cannot find any sensible way to achieve either of these without causing more confusion by breaking all the cordova tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to modify an activity's entry in the Manifest.xml, you can do so from the plugin's plugin.xml file.

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']" mode="overwrite">
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:label="NewLabel" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
</edit-config>
```

With this,you can remove the MainActivity's entry or change it so that it's not longer the launcher activity for the app.

[Source](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config)

Answer (score 10):

There are two possible solutions to this:

### 1. Use a hook to modify MainActivity

Use a [hook](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html) to copy a custom `MainActivity.java` into `platforms/android/src/[packageName]/` and override the default Cordova `MainActivity`.

For example, a `before_build` hook can be added to `<platform name="android">` section of the `config.xml` like this:

```xml
<hook type="before_build" src="scripts/updateMainActivity.sh" />
```

Where `scripts/updateMainActivity.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp MainActivity.java platforms/android/src/[packageName]/
```

(You can also write hooks with nodeJS, which is good for cross-platform compatibility)

### 2. Use cordova-custom-config to remove MainActivity

With [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config), all you need to do is add the following to the `<platform name="android">` section of your config.xml:

```xml
<preference name="android-manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']" delete="true" />
```

Note: You will need cordova-custom-config >= 3.0.0.

This is the solution I went with, since I am already using cordova-custom-config.

Comment: Hi, I have a requirement as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408235/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-app-icon-on-home-screen-cordova-angularapp/42408335#42408335  I tried the step 2, but I am still seeing the App icon on the APP Homepage. Could you please help here.

Comment: Where is MainActivity going? I have it inside the before_build folder but I get the error "cp: can not stat 'MainActivity.java': No such file or directory" with the first option.

Comment: You don't need a `before_build` folder. Put `updateMainActivity.sh` in `scripts`, and put `MainActivity.java` in the project root with the `config.xml`.