# is it possible to hide the APP icon on home screen (Cordova - AngularApp)

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have a requirement as:
There are two Apps APP "A" and APP "B". Here, APP B should open by any event triggered from APP A. For doing the same, I need to install both the apps on the device and is working fine. Here, I want to restrict the APP B from opening directly (from APP Launchpad/ Home Screen) so that it should open only from APP A.
APP B is an hybrid APP built using Cordova.

Could you please suggest any possibility of handling the scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove an app from default launcher then remove the following line in **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Naresh, But this option is present when the app is built natively on Android. Here, I have an hybrid app using cordova. so, I needed something in cordova ...

Answer (score 0):

With [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config), you should be able to add something like this to your config.xml:

```
<preference name="android-manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']/intent-filter" delete="true" />
```

You will probably have to delete `platforms/android` and run `cordova prepare` after making any changes.

Check the `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml` to see if it has worked.

Make sure you have cordova-custom-config >= 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

*If you want to remove launcher then replace this in AndroidManifest.xml file*

**category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"**

*replace to :*

**category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"**