# How to add code in MainApplication file in cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to create a cordova app which will utilize adobe sdks, for that I need to make changes to the MainApplication file and MainActivity file and manifest file too, for android platform. How can that be done.
I am a beginner in cordova and don't have much idea about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at hooks? I think that's the most common way to edit the androidManifest: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/appdev/hooks/ not sure about mainApplication and activity. I think you also do that with a hook, like suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530004/cordova-modify-or-remove-mainactivity

Comment: Should i use the same approach If I am building my app using ionic/angular with cordova??

Comment: I haven't used angular/ionic. But I believe so.